# how to remove "created on" text in joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla3.1, joomla3.2

how can I remove, for example "created on", text in article? 
I just want to remove the text not date itself. I've removed the icon with css but text and date in this case are written together in time tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the article manager, if you click "options", you can set what you want to turn off.  In this case, "Show Create Date" is an option.

If you are creating pages by assigning them to menu items, then you may need to look under the "options" setting of the menu item itself.

Edit: Following your comments - to just remove such text, download the file:  language/en-GB/en-GB.com_content.ini (change en-GB if using language overrides)

This will show you a list of text strings used by that component.

You can then use the language manager ( extensions - language manager ) to override these.

(You could also search for text using the language manager, but I find the downloading the language file quicker)

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your reply but thats not exactly what I want. As I've written I just want to remote the text before date not date itself.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks again, something like that already crossed my mind but :) ... I'll have the same problem if the lang file is updated. I've hoped that there is a little more elegant solution for this but I guess lang file will have to do. :)

Comment: If language updates don't work, take a look at overriding the com_content view by copying from compoents/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to your template's html folder (read up on Joomla overrides if you don't know how to do that).  There, you can use php to override the display of this parameter.

Comment: Thanks, yes that will do the job, I'll take a look.